# How to calculate the difference of two vectors optimally?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I've tried to remove two vectors by following:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> diff_vectors(std::vector<T> v, std::vector<T> v0) {
    std::vector<T> _v;
    for (T e : v) {
        if (std::count(v0.begin(), v0.end(), e) == 0) _v.push_back(e);
    }
    return _v;
}
```

However, it seems to run too slow for big vectors `v` or `v0`. By the size of the vector `v` being `m` and `v0` being `n`, the worst-case time complexity would be `O(mn)`. Can it be optimized, so that the worst-case time complexity would be less? If not, any proof that it's not possible?

Comment: Not sure whether I understood your use case. Are you calculating the difference of two sets?

Comment: In your code, you are extracting the values in `v` that are not in `v0`. But what about the values in `v0` that are not in `v` ?

Comment: Not with unsorted vectors, you can implement the subtraction as a "negated merge" in `O(m+n)` if they are sorted - which is `O(mlogm + nlogn)`. If you use hashing, you can bring it lower maybe, cache locality is a thing.

Comment: You take the vectors by value for no good reason, so that's going to create copies. Also, taking `T` by value in the loop may also be costly

Comment: Since `v` is passed by value, why not simply remove any elements from it that are elements of `v0` - and then return the modified `v`?     You can probably also optimise further if some properties of the vectors are known (e.g. are they sorted?)

Comment: `count(...) == 0` would be better expressed as `none_of(...)`.

Comment: @Fareanor They would make no change. It doesn't matter if they exist or not

Comment: @sbh Then you are **not** calculating the **difference** between two vectors (as the question title suggests) ;)

Comment: @Fareanor The existence of an element that is in `v0` but not `v` would have no change on `v - v0`

Comment: e.g. `{1, 2, 3} - {2, 3, 4, 5} = {1, 2, 3} - {2, 3, 4}`. The `5` here can exist or not, leaving the difference unchanged.

Comment: How are the vectors populated? What are they used for? Perhaps having vectors isn't optimal for what you are trying to achieve. How often do you need to do this operation? What are the typical `T`s?

Comment: @Fareanor OP wants to calculate the [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement).

Comment: @interjay Yes I understood lately ^^ Thanks for the notice though

Comment: Simple solution here: https://www.techiedelight.com/get-difference-between-two-vectors-in-cpp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to compute a [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), also called relative complement in set theory. The standard library already has a function for that: [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

It requires the inputs to be sorted. If you don't know whether the input vectors are sorted, just sort them. The total complexity will be `O(m log m + n log n)` which is better than `O(mn)`.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> diff_vectors(std::vector<T> v, std::vector<T> v0) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::sort(v0.begin(), v0.end());
    std::vector<T> _v;
    std::set_difference(
        v.begin(), v.end(), v0.begin(), v0.end(),
        std::back_inserter(_v)
    );
    return _v;
}
```

Of course, if you know that the inputs are sorted beforehand, just use `std::set_difference` directly. The complexity in this case is just `O(m + n)` (cppreference specifies: "at most `2 * (m + n) - 1` comparisons using `operator<`").